# Sumar dos números muy grandes dados como strings

Tags: javascript

Estoy practicando mi `javascript` en [CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com) y me he topado con esta pregunta:

> Escribe una función que devuelva el `String` con la suma de dos números. Los parametros son dos numeros pero de tipo `String`.

Notas:

- Los inputs son grandes.
- Los inputs son `strings` que contienen solo numeros.
- Los numeros son positivos.

Por lo que hice:

```
function add(a, b) {
  return (Number(a) + Number(b))+"";
}
```

Para numeros pequeños no hay problema, me pasa los test bien, pero para numeros grandes falla al cambiar la notación.

Tests:

```
✔ Test Passed: Value == '100'
✔ Test Passed: Value == '8670'
✔ Test Passed: Value == '5'
✘ sumStrings('712569312664357328695151392', '8100824045303269669937') - 
    Expected: '712577413488402631964821329', instead got: '7.125774134884027e+26'
✘ sumStrings('50095301248058391139327916261', '81055900096023504197206408605') - 
    Expected: '131151201344081895336534324866', instead got: '1.3115120134408189e+29'
```

Probablemente sea una chorrada pero no se me ocurre. **¿Cómo puedo solventar este problema?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Realmente no falla, la suma la realiza correctamente, simplemente que `CodeWars` no querrá como resultado ese formato.

**Por ejemplo:**

El número `7.125774134884027e+26` es lo mismo que `712577413488402631964821329` pero simplemente con distinta notación.

No he conseguido otra solución menos compleja que la que te propongo a continuación:

```
function add(num1, num2) {
    num1 = num1.split('');
  num2 = num2.split('');

  num1 = num1.map(function (num) {
    return parseInt(num, 10);
  });

  num2 = num2.map(function (num) {
    return parseInt(num, 10);
  });

    if (num2.length > num1.length) {
    return _add(num2, num1);
  } else {
    return _add(num1, num2)
  }
}

function _add(num1, num2) {
    var num1_idx = num1.length-1;
  var num2_idx = num2.length-1;
  var remainder = 0;

  for (; num1_idx > -1; num1_idx--, num2_idx--) {
    var sum = num1[num1_idx] + remainder;

    if (num2_idx > -1) {
        sum += num2[num2_idx];
    }

        if (sum <= 9 || num1_idx === 0) {
        remainder = 0;
        num1[num1_idx] = sum;
    } else if (sum >= 10) {
        remainder = 1;
      num1[num1_idx] = sum - 10;
    }

    console.log(remainder);
  }

  return num1.join('').replace(/^[0]+/g,"");
}
```

Utilizándolo de la siguiente manera:

```
document.write(add("712577413488402631964821329", "712577413488402631964821329"));
```

Tienes el GitHub con el creador de este método [aquí](https://gist.github.com/armandocanals/339e2ae831080fa9f825a71cf45f8ecb)

---

Otra solución que he encontrado es utilizar librerías externas para ello como [BigInteger](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) y poder utilizarlo así:

```
var n = bigInt("91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250")
    .plus("91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250");
```

Comment: aaaaamigo. librerias externas aparte (gracias por la recomendacion) pensaba que el problema era tema de tipo de variable por no entrar  el numero y por eso pasaba a notacion cientifica y la solucion seria algun tipo de tratamiento de tipos.. lo que tu propones es un algoritmo que sume uno a uno y arraste a la siguiente suma el reminder no ? no se me ocurrió hacerlo de la manera ... *de colegio* (a lo papel y boli ahahah) Gracias!

Comment: pasó a la perfección salvo por un fallo `sumStrings('00103', '08567') - Expected: '8670', instead got: '08670'` (pero quitando los ceros al principio lo resuelve.)

Comment: Exacto! Javascript a cierto límite, ya empieza a mostrar los números con esa notación científica, así que hay que hacerlo casi una suma *manual*

Comment: si quieres añadirlo, en tu `return` del metodo `_add` puse: `return num1.join('').replace(/^[0]+/g,"");`.

Comment: @lois6b Editado ;)

Answer (score 6):

Existe una clase BigInt nativa que está a día de hoy en fase experimental (el estándar ECMAScript la está contemplando) y que sólo está presente en los navegadores Chrome y Firefox (en este caso hay que activarla manualmente) y en NodeJS.

El formato de esta clase no usa el científico y permite el manejo de números enteros arbitrariamente grandes sin perder precisión:

```js
function sumStrings(a, b) {
  return BigInt(a) + BigInt(b)
}

let resultado=sumStrings('712569312664357328695151392', '8100824045303269669937');
console.log(resultado.toString());
```

**Actualización**: La propuesta se considera aprobada y será parte de la revisón del estándar ES2020

Answer (score 3):

`JavaScript` usa [double-precision float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) en el trabajo con números y puede representar números de manera segura entre `-(2^53 - 1)` y `2^53 - 1`. Eso significa que debes trabajar con números entre `-9007199254740991` y `9007199254740991`, para números más grandes los representará como lo que te devuelve `CodeWars` (notación científica). Si necesitas trabajar con números más grandes te recomiendo utilizar una librería como [BigNumbers.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/).

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. en este caso concreto no puedo usar librerias externas asi que la solucion es un algoritmo como el de la respuesta de cnbandticoot.

Comment: @lois6b, exacto, si no puedes usar librerías externas debes hacer tú tu propio algoritmo. Pero cuidado, lo mismo me ocurrió en [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/), te pueden enviar un input con millones de números y algoritmos como estos entonces terminarían en un `timeout`. Para trabajar con números grandes lamentablemente lo mejor es irse a por otro lenguaje.

Comment: ya .. ya me tocará otro lenguaje, ahora practico javascript hehe

Answer (score 3):

Yo lo resolví imitando el método del colegio:

tomo la cifra menos significativa de ambos números. Las sumo, anoto la unidad y, si es necesario, me reservo una. Esto equivale a iterar sobre el string más largo e ir quitando de ambos string la cifra menos significativa, sumándolas, obteniendo la decena y luego vuelta a iterar sumando también la decena (que al inicio vale 0).

Ver el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
function sumabigInt(num1,num2) {

            var num1 = String(num1),
                num2 = String(num2),
                acumulado = '',
                arr1 = num1.split(''),
                arr2 = num2.split(''),
                decena = 0,
                maxlength = Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length);

           var sumadigitos=function(a, b, c) {
                var suma = Number(a) + Number(b) + Number(c),
                    nuevonumero = suma % 10,
                    segundacifra = Math.floor(suma / 10);
                acumulado = String(nuevonumero) + acumulado;
                return segundacifra;
            };

 
            for (var i = 0; i < maxlength; i++) {
                var val1 = arr1.length ? arr1.pop() : 0,
                    val2 = arr2.length ? arr2.pop() : 0;
                decena = sumadigitos(val1, val2, decena);
            }
            if (decena > 0) {
                acumulado = String(decena) + acumulado;
            }
            return acumulado;
 }
console.log(sumabigInt(  '712569312664357328695151392', '8100824045303269669937'));
```

El siguiente ejemplo va imprimiendo una tablita con jQuery.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var num1 = '712569312664357328695151392',
                num2 = '8100824045303269669937',
                acumulado = '',
                arr1 = num1.split(''),
                arr2 = num2.split(''),
                iteracion = 1,
                decena = 0,
                maxlength = Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length);

            function sumadigitos(a, b, c) {
                var suma = Number(a) + Number(b) + Number(c),
                    nuevonumero = suma % 10,
                    segundacifra = Math.floor(suma / 10);
                acumulado = String(nuevonumero) + acumulado;
                return segundacifra;
            }

            function imprime(iteracion) {
                var newrow = jQuery('<tr></tr>');
                newrow.append('<td >Iteracion ' + iteracion + '</td>');
                newrow.append('<td >' + arr1.join('') + '</td>');
                newrow.append('<td >' + arr2.join('') + '</td>');
                newrow.append('<td >' + acumulado + '</td>');
                newrow.appendTo('#container');
            }
            imprime(iteracion);
            for (var i = 0; i < maxlength; i++) {
                var val1 = arr1.length ? arr1.pop() : 0,
                    val2 = arr2.length ? arr2.pop() : 0;
                decena = sumadigitos(val1, val2, decena);
                iteracion++;
                imprime(iteracion);
            }
            if (decena > 0) {
                acumulado = String(decena) + acumulado;
                imprime('final');
            }
        });
```

```css
td {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="container" style="width:550px;font-size:9px;">
            <tr>
                <th width="15%">
                    Comentario
                </th>
                <th width="26%">
                    num1
                </th>
                <th width="26%">
                    num2
                </th>
                <th width="29%">
                    acumulado
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta. me gusta mucho que lo hicieras ejecutable y grafico con las tablas ^^ . aunque el metodo `de colegio` es el que ya hizo antes @cnbandicoot

Comment: confieso que miré la soución de @cnbandicoot y no entendí absolutamente nada así que me puse a pensarla desde cero. Por eso dicen que grandes mentes piensan igual :D

Comment: si, admito que tu codigo es más claro a golpe de vista pero la idea es la misma. y auqnue en codewars no puedo, es buena su recomendacion de librerias externas. HAHAHA grandes mentes XD

Answer (score 0):

Hoy se resuelve con el nuevo tipo BigInt(), no obstante son mucho màs didàcticas las soluciones antes propuestas.

function sumStrings (a,b){

```
let stra = BigInt(a);
let strb = BigInt(b);


if (isNaN(a)|| isNaN(b)){
    return (stra.toString(), strb.toString());
}else {
  
    let res = ((stra + strb).toLocaleString());
    res = res.replace(/\./g,'').replace(/,/g , '');
    return res;

}
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta pero la de @Pablolozano ya indica lo de BigInt