# Realizar cálculos en php y comunicarlos con la interfaz hecha en angular

Tags: php, angularjs-2.0

Después de seguir algunos cursos de angular y laravel, estoy montando un sitio web para geólogos con más que nada texto. Voy a hacer el sistema de rutas principal con angular 2.
Estoy haciendo una aplicación, dentro de la web, enteramente escrita en typescript/javascript. Lee archivo excel de rocas y representa los puntos en gráficos XY, calculando regresiones lineales, cuadradas y cúbicas para la nube de puntos.
Estoy teniendo problemas de devolución de NaN para obtener la curva y=ax^3+bx^2+c, para el caso de puntos muy juntos en X. Supongo que es debido a que javascript se atasca a la hora de calcular determinantes de 5x5 con sumandos de x^8.
Mi pregunta es si puedo realizar los cálculos en php. Es decir, por ejemplo retornar a angular un json que dependa de parámetros que vienen de la aplicación en angular.
No sé si esto es posible, de este o algún otro modo, pero me sería de gran utilidad para no sobrecargar los computadores faltos de recursos, y tal vez para ganar precición.

Comment: Creo que ninguno de los dos lenguajes son muy buenos con las matemáticas. El problema en PHP viene a la hora de manejar números grandes, según el servidor se admite un tamaño máximo u otro, quiero decir que la misma implementación de una variable, en un servidor podría almacenar en un número de cifras no admisible en otro, pero si no necesitas números de mas de 9 cifras no creo que tengas problemas.

Comment: Me han hablado de fortran y tal, pero mis conocimientos son muy limitados. No sabría compilar para mac, w, linux. No sé si podría usar phyton en un proyecto web, pero en principio se me abre un mundo de tenerlo que reprogramar. Tengo las regresiones hechas en javascript y las curvas representadas en el canvas.

Comment: Creo que el problema en javascript viene a la hora de multiplicar o dividir decimales. Falla para intervalos cortos de x. Pero en principio no se desvía mucho y representa casi siempre. Mi idea es poner un log 'No fue posible calcular la regresión' para cuando de NaN. Me seriviría mucho usar php solo por el hecho de no sobrecargar el navegador del usuario, pero no sé si se puede hacer en un proyecto angular. En el caso de usar json tendría que retornar un json que depende de variables js.

Comment: Python se esta usando mucho en big data, chain blocks y cosas así última mente y creo que te podría servir. Se puede incluir un módulo python en proyectos php, no sé como pero lo he visto alguna vez. Aunque yo veo mas fácil implementar por separado un microservicio solo para los cálculos. Si no maneja datos sensibles, no sería nada complicado y puede mejorar el resultado final de cara al rendimiento.

Comment: Gracias por interesarse. Voy a investigar porque sería muy adecuado poder incorporar phyton en mi proyecto web, ya sea un micorservicio o su instalación en el sevidor con frames como Django. Javascript funciona bien hasta no sé qué punto, y dada su respuesta imagino php no es mejor. Da las rectas x^3 con precisión de varios decimales, con lo que puedo mostrar los resultados a mis alumnos correctamente. Pero, por si le interesa el tema para su profesión, de repente, al incrementar los puntos o disminuir su incremento en x, hace crash, y retorna NotANumber.

Comment: En el cálculo de un determinante de 5x5 con un sumatorio x^8. Imagino el límite viene de calcular multiplicaciones de decimales. Pero mis mates no me alcanzan a entender por qué da NaN y no simplemente se desvía.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con cualquier lenguaje de programación "de propósito general" vas a tener limitaciones en el uso de números con coma flotante, ya sea Java, Javascript, PHP, C, C++, Python... porque todos hacen uso del mismo hardware, que es donde está la verdadera limitación.

Si no quieres abandonar Javascript, puedes probar a usar alguna librería que te permita usar el equivalente a la clase Java BigDecimal, como por ejemplo [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/). (Hay muchas otras, pero se sale fuera del objetivo de esta respuesta el recomendarte una, el enlace es sólo una muestra de una que, a su vez, recomienda en su documentación otras dependiendo de tus necesidades).

Si quieres trabajar con PHP, también tienes librerías similares [(por ejemplo, esta es la primera que he encontrado *googleando*)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).

Obviamente, estas librerías solucionan la limitación del hardware a base de no usarlo, con lo que el rendimiento es menor, deberás comprobar si esto se convierte en un problema.

Comment: Hola Pablo. Esto tiene pinta de comentario, no de respuesta. Además que estas dando recomendaciones de librerias y eso indicaria que la pregunta es basada en opinones

Comment: Quiero dar a entender que, aunque ni PHP ni Javascript trabajar bien con números grandes en coma flotante, existen librerías que solucionan las limitaciones. He puesto el ejemplo de dos de ellas, pero realmente lo que quiero exponer es que puede no ser necesario cambiar de lenguaje de programación mediante el uso de otras herramientas

Comment: ahh. Si, en [esta pregunta mia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52373/suma-de-numeros-enormes) me pasaba eso y me recomendaron el uso de esa misma libreria

Comment: Me han recomendado usar phyton si trabajo con datos científicos. Ya estoy en dos cursos y creo que lo voy a instalar en el servidor con Django. Pero antes de nada voy a probar con esa librería a ver si así no peta para la x^3. ty!