# Retornar digitos completos como string

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando convertir un numero entero largo de 42 digitos a string el numero es:

```
3101201907179244241900110010020000000931934567813
```

he intentado lo siguiente:

```
const myNumb = 3101201907179244241900110010020000000931934567813;
alert( myNumb.toLocaleString('fullwide', { useGrouping: false }) );
```

resultado:

```
3101201907179240000000000000000000000000000000000
```

he intentado diferentes soluciones como estas:
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Ninguna me ha dado resultado quiza alguien me podria comentar como solucionar este problema gracias..!!

Comment: Nunca he tenido la necesidad de usar algo así pero tal vez alguna de estas librerías te ayude: https://www.slant.co/topics/5804/~javascript-library-for-dealing-with-large-numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El número que estás usando es demasiado grande, JavaScript no lo soporta sin perder precisión.  El máximo entero que se puede usar de manera segura es `9007199254740991`, puedes obtenerlo con `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.  A menos que necesites hacer cálculos con ese número te recomiendo que mejor lo guardes como un `string`.

```
const numero = '3101201907179244241900110010020000000931934567813';
```

---

Si necesitas hacer operaciones existen algunas alternativas:

Hay una nueva clase `BigInt` que sirve para manipular números enteros de precisión arbitraria pero es soportada por muy pocos navegadores.  Actualmente solo [Chrome y Opera](https://caniuse.com/#search=bigint).

Utilizar una librería de números grandes.  Existen librerías para manejar este tipo de números sin perder precisión pero no tienen el mismo rendimiento que el objeto nativo `BigInt`.

Comment: gracias la solucion fue pasarla a String algo asi: var numero = " ' " +12345678978798.....+" ' " ;

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente JavaScript no soporta este numero muy grande, como dijo el compañero,
la solución sería convertir el numero a string y devolverlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
  const numero = '3101201907179244241900110010020000000931934567813';
  var n = numero.toString();
 alert(n);
```

Otra solución que he encontrado es utilizar librerías externas para ello como [BigInteger](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) y poder utilizarlo así:

```
var n = bigInt("91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250")
    .plus("91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250");
```

Te dejo una pregunta [similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52373/suma-de-numeros-enormes),
Saludos